# How to insert a photo file into an entity in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot

I have created  an entity called "BusinessAccount".

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "business_account")
@Getter
@Setter
public class BusinessAccount extends AbstractEntity {
 private String name;
 private String surName;
 ...
```

So every account should have its own photo, so I am thinking how to save a photo to my DB, any ideas? Would be glad for your help.
What I have tried is that to make a different "Endpoint" , in which photos will be stored in the DB , but the loading so slow, so that's why I wanted to add the Photo to the Entity or add it to the Body.

Comment: storing images into db is a bad idea due to multiple reasons; Rather I would suggest to store the images into file system and store the link for the image into your db table.

Comment: You can use BLOB , yes it is bad idea , better store the image cloud like s3 and get the url and store those url in DB columns.

Answer (score -1):

Take

```
private byte[] photo;
```

in your entity class. And in the database set the datatype to byte array.

Store the base64-encoded photo in the database.